# Transform translateY in css without actually moving the Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a  element and I want to make an animation. I made an background that kind of divides the screen by two. One site is white and the other one is colorful. I made the text match the background. It´s difficult to explain, so here is my code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

#section_1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-50deg, #fff calc(50% - 1px), #fff0 calc(50% + 1px)), linear-gradient(300deg, #fff calc(30vH - 2px), #fff0 30vH), linear-gradient(50deg, #fff0 calc(60vH - 2px), #047bfd 60vH), linear-gradient(150deg, #003975 calc(60vH - 2px), #002A56 60vH);
}

#section_1 h1 {
  color: #fff0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: calc(50vH - 40px) 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-50deg, #004892 calc(50% + -5px), #fff calc(50% + -3px));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;

  /* Animation */
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}

#section_1 h1.active { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
```

```html
<div id="section_1">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    let getH1 = document.querySelector("#section_1 h1");

    getH1.className = "active";
  }, 200);
</script>
```

I´ve added the active class at the end of my HTML file with JS to start the animation. But the color of the text moves too. If put a  into the  the color is still there, but the transform doesn´t work. The transform works if I set the display of the span element to inline-block, but then the color is not there. It´s #fff0 so the background isn´t related to the text anymore. Has someone an idea on how to do that animation, with the color?

([Codepen](https://codepen.io/rangobro/pen/yLaVZwM))

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Ups, don't coding for a while, I didn't know. Delete comment above.

Comment: It is valid. It is #[red][green][blue][alpha]. Alpha is the visibility

Answer (score 1):

Since your background cover `100vh` apply the same layer to the text using `fixed` and instead of transform use `top` for the animation (transform won't work with `fixed`)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    let getH1 = document.querySelector("#section_1 h1");

    getH1.className = "active";
  }, 200);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

#section_1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
     linear-gradient(-50deg, #fff calc(50% - 1px), #fff0 calc(50% + 1px)), /* copy this layer */
     linear-gradient(300deg, #fff calc(30vH - 2px), #fff0 30vH), 
     linear-gradient(50deg, #fff0 calc(60vH - 2px), #047bfd 60vH), 
     linear-gradient(150deg, #003975 calc(60vH - 2px), #002A56 60vH);
}

#section_1 h1 {
  color: #fff0;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: calc(50vH - 40px) 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-50deg, #004892 calc(50% - 1px), #fff calc(50% + 1px)) fixed; /* here */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  /* Animation */
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -40px;
}

#section_1 h1.active {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="section_1">
  <h1>Some Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @FieteSchwettmann it's not more working? :)

Comment: I thought I wrote the comment. The problem is that the background stays in place on scroll.

Comment: @FieteSchwettmann there is no scroll on your code and no other content than what you show so I gave an answer based on that. Everything beyond this is out of the scope of your question unless you edit it to add more details